# php artisan migrate not working properly

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-artisan

i am new to laravel and i ran the auth file to make a register and login etc...

i have 3 migrations file inside the migrations folder: user table reset_password table and user_profile table: the problem is when i ran: `php artisan migrate` it only create the user table without the 2 other table so i tried these commands:`php artisan migrate:rollback, php artisan migrate:refresh, php artisan config:cache php artisan config cache:clear` and then i ran :`php artisan migrate` and only user table was created... any idea? thank you

Comment: try to delete all tables from your database and try `php artisan migrate` again

Comment: On which version of laravel you are working ?

Comment: i did it and same result @Onix

Comment: laravel 5.4 @MayankPandeyz

Comment: Try `php artisan make:auth`

Comment: Any errors? Anything in `storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Answer (score 0):

I am also facing the same issue, while you are running `php artisan migrate`, the command starts migrating the table and while migrating `users` table it is throwing some error like:

> [Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
>   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key
>   was too long; max key      length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table
>   `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))

so, only user table is migrated and the process stops with the above error. If this is the issue, then you have to solve it and after that delete the `users` table and again migrate, every thing will be fine.

To fix the above issue, all you have to do is to edit your `app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` file and add to the boot method a default string length like:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

and again migrate, everything will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I Found the solution for this

First set this in App/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

```
public function boot()
    {
        Schema::defaultStringLength(191);

    }
```

Then Migrate Cmd And at Last

**php artisan migrate:fresh**

after that migration works